# Is it possible to identify the length / size of a readable stream?

Tags: node.js, knox-amazon-s3-client

I'm trying to resize a file in node using gm.js and use the `.stream()` to create a readable stream of the resized image. Now I want to upload it using knox.js `.putStream()` but `Content-Length` is a required header. Is it possible to identify the size of the readable stream so I can use it in the `Content-Length` header?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: I dont think you can read it from the stream itself, since it basically doesnt do a "look up" to see how much is still coming, but keeps parsing until the end. But maybe you could check the file-size in advance with `fs.stats(FILENAME)`?

Comment: You can upload without `Content-Length` to S3 using multipart. At least both [`knox-mpu`](https://github.com/nathanoehlman/knox-mpu) and the official [`aws-sdk`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) modules support multipart uploading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your files aren't too large, you could bufferize your stream using [raw-body](https://github.com/stream-utils/raw-body) module before uploading it to S3:

```
var rawBody = require('raw-body');
var knox = require('knox');

function putStream(stream, filepath, headers, next) {
  rawBody(stream, function(err, buffer) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    headers['Content-Length'] = buffer.length;
    knox.putBuffer(buffer, filepath, headers, next);
  });
};
```

If your files are extremely large, it may be better to use mscdex's solution with [knox-mpu](https://github.com/nathanoehlman/knox-mpu) module.